# Why is Ajv unable to resolve reference during compile?

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, ajv

The following is an example of the JSON schema that I am trying to compile and use for validation.  To accomplish this I am using the ['ajv' npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv).

Here is the code that I am running ...

```
var ajv = require('ajv')();

var contactSchema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Contact",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "work": { "$ref": "#definitions/phone" },
        "home": { "$ref": "#definitions/phone" },
    },
    "definitions": {
        "phone": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["number"],
            "properties": {
                "number": { "type": "string" },
                "extension": { "type": "string" }
            }
        }
    }
};

var validator = ajv.compile(contactSchema);
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following exception ..

```
Error: can't resolve reference #definitions/phone from id #
```

Has anyone else run into this kind of issue?  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reference is incorrect (although it's valid), it should be #/definitions/phone

Alternatively, to make it work you can add `"id": "#definitions/phone"` inside phone schema, but it is more common to use `"id": "#phone"` (and update $refs too).

Comment: That did fix the issue but could you explain why `#/definitions/phone` worked and the `#definitions/phone` does not?  All the documentation from the developer would imply otherwise.  Thanks!

Comment: What documentation you refer to? I am the developer btw :) That's by the spec, the reference within the current schema is # followed by JSON pointer, JSON pointer starts from "/"

Comment: Great library, thank you for contributing it for the rest of us.  As for your question, I could have sworn that I saw that in examples on the json-schema.org website but for the life of me I can't find any examples as proof.  So I must be going blind or insane.  Thank you for the prompt response.